# Find the maximum and minimum points of $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the maximum and minimum points of $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ on the interval $[-1,1]$
Do these occur at critical points?

So I have the first derivative as
$f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ and then when I set it equal to zero there are no solutions so where do I go from here?

Comment: You might wanna double check that derivative!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! The derivative is 2/3 x x^(/1/3) but I know that if a function has a max at an interior point then f'(c) = 0 but how do I find the max and min values?

Comment: @Strants: Not quite true. Extrema can occur at boundary points of the domain as well. These need not be critical points. Example: consider the identity function on any compact subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hmmm. . . I could've sworn the text I used defined critical points in such a way that boundary points on a domain where critical points, but I guess that's not the standard definition.  My bad; I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This function is not even differentiable in the point $x=0$ since $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=+\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=-\infty$$ So the criterion of the first derivative for a max/min does not apply!

Split the interval in two intervals $I_1=[-1,0)$ and $I_2=(0,1]$. In these intervals there is no problem with the derivative. In $I_1$ $f$ is monotone decreasing and in $I_2$ monotone increasing. So the only candidates for extrema are the points $\{-1,1\}$ for maxima and $\{0\}$ for minimum (but not with the use of the derivative criterion, since it does not apply!) Find the solutions by checking the candidates (there are only three of them).

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x) = \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

The question is asking you about the maximum and minimum points of $f(x)$ in that specific interval. Setting the derivative to $0$ will give you the *absolute* minima/maxima, which are not necessarily the maximum/minimum points in the interval.

$$0 = \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$

This function has no absolute minima/maxima; the derivative will never equal $0$. It makes sense from the graph too. However, since you're looking for the minimum and maximum points in the *interval*, you're just looking for places where $f(x)$ is lowest or highest between $-1$ and $1$ (inclusive).

[image]

By graphing, we see that it is lowest at $(0, 0)$, making it a minimum, and highest at $(\pm1,1)$, the relative maximum. Again, these are not critical points, but they are your maxima/minima.

Without graphing, the only real way you can do this is by noticing that it's $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}=(x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. In other words, negative or positive $x$, $y$ will always be positive. Also that $y$ is increasing as $|x|$ increases. Meaning that 0 is the lowest, and $\pm1$ is highest in the interval.

Comment: Okay thank you! So those are my max and min points but the critical points only happen at the absolute max or min? So these aren't critical points